# Set Notation for Distinct Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As a note, this is for an assignment. I know what I'm wanting to express and have been trying to figure out the correct notation to express this but I'm hitting a bit of a wall with it.

The domain of a function has n distinct real numbers. I'm trying to express this as $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^n|x_i\neq x_j\}$ but how do I add that this is for all i and j in the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ except where $i=j$? Or is this unnecessary in this instance?

Comment: $\{x_i\in\mathbb{R^n}:i=1,2,...,n \ \text{and}\  x_i\neq\ x_j \ \text{whenever}\  i\neq j\}$.

Comment: I'd typically write that either $X = \{ x_1, \ldots x_n \in \Bbb R\}, |X| = n$, or use the solution Janitha wrote while I was mistyping this...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "The domain of a function **has** $n$ distinct real numbers". Does the domain consist of just five numbers, or is it an ensemble of five-element sets?

Comment: It was written as the domain of the function containing n separate elements rather than one set of elements of size n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to write is, imo, $\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \forall i, j \in \{1,...,n\}, i\neq j \implies x_i \neq x_j \}$.

Of course when you are more comfortable with this kind of thing, you can write abbreviations for it, such as $\{(x_i)\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \neq x_j \}$, where the $i\neq j$ is implicit, but do remember that "technically", this isn't correct (although both writings $(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(x_i)_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are fine in any case)

Comment: Thank you for this, it is very similar to what I ended up going with but I filled the gaps with plain English not knowing what notation to use. I'll remember this for future.